# Relay: Cannot read property 'fetchKey' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

Im trying to use the new relay hooks but getting this error:

```
import React, { Fragment, Suspense, useEffect } from 'react';
import Banner from './banner/Banner.react';

const { graphql, useQueryLoader, usePreloadedQuery } = require('react-relay/hooks');

const query = graphql`
  query HomeQuery {
    viewer {
      id
      email
      ...Banner_viewer
    }
  }
`;

const HomeContainer = () => {
  const [queryReference, loadQuery] = useQueryLoader(query);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadQuery({});
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
      <Fragment>
        <Home queryReference={queryReference} />
      </Fragment>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

const Home = ({ queryReference }) => {
  const data = usePreloadedQuery(query, queryReference);
  console.log('data:', data);
  return (
    <>
      <Banner viewer={data?.viewer} />
      <div>HOME PAGE</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeContainer;
```

Error:

```
usePreloadedQuery.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchKey' of null
    at usePreloadedQuery (usePreloadedQuery.js:38)
    at Home (Home.jsx:34)
```

Comment: `queryReference != null` - read docs!

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if `queryReference` is not null, so you don't call `usePreloadedQuery` with a null value in your Home component. Try with:

```
return (
  <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
    <Fragment>
      {queryReference != null && <Home queryReference={queryReference} />}
    </Fragment>
  </Suspense>
);
```

Comment: It's strange that the official documentation doesn't say anything about it https://relay.dev/docs/guided-tour/rendering/loading-states/.

Comment: Suspense just does nothing this way since it can be easier replaced with tertiary operator which makes all effort using it as minimum weird.

Comment: Suspense is still doing its job. If the  query reference is not null it doesn't mean that the query was consumed and finished. You can find an example in the documentation [here](https://relay.dev/docs/api-reference/use-preloaded-query/).